# Wildcard for read_template

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following method in my python email code

```
def main():
    names, emails = get_contacts('mycontacts.txt') # read contacts
    message_template = read_template('message.txt')
```

I'd like to be able to have it read all files that end in .txt into the message_template.

Something like:

```
message_template = read_template('*.txt')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's the re module which you could use to match on a wildcard or the glob module. re is python's builtin regex module while glob does unix style pathname pattern expansion.

Comment: you can't read templates with `*` . You can only use `glob.glob("*.txt")` to get all filenames in folder and later use loop to read all templates separatelly and eventually concatenate them into one string.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I will try the glob option

Comment: btw: I'm not sure if it will give filenames always in the same order so it is good to use numbers in filenames `1-message.txt`, `2-footer.txt` and sort filenames before you start reading and concatenating files.

Comment: Excellent point, thanks

Comment: The filenames wont be in any specific order, `glob.glob` depends on `os.listdir`, whose order is [arbitrary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)